# How to get toggle switch state in vue app

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I'm testing Bootstrap 5 alpha. They removed jQuery from dependencies and this is an improvement if the framework is used for the UI of a Vue-based application. In Bootstrap 4.5, I've noticed that the toggle switches are not working if all the B/S 4 dependencies are correctly included in the main.js file of the app.

In v5 all works fine, due to the Vanilla JavaScript usage. I want to ask how I can get the state of a toggle switch when clicked in my Vue app. I want to create some settings using this Bootstrap component, but I'm not sure how to manage the on/off state using the `v-on:click.prevent` event binding. Any suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: Alternatively you could use [Bootstrap-Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org), which has a [switch checkbox](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-checkbox#switch-style-checkboxes). Though it's using Bootstrap 4 currently, and not Bootstrap 5, but it is planned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `v-model` directive to create two-way data bindings.

```html
<div class='form-check form-switch'>
  <input class='form-check-input' type='checkbox' id='flexSwitchCheckDefault' v-model='switch'>
  <label class='form-check-label' for='flexSwitchCheckDefault'>Default switch checkbox input</label>
</div>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/97pLd2j8/)

Or use as a component, for example, `switch-component`.

```html
<switch-component
  id='switch'
  v-model='switch'>
  Default switch
</switch-component>
```

```js
Vue.component('switch-component', {
  props: ['id', 'value'],
  inheritAttrs: false,
  template: `
    <div class='form-check form-switch'>
      <input
        class='form-check-input'
        type='checkbox'
        v-bind='$attrs'
        :checked='value'
        @change='$emit("input", $event.target.checked)'>
      <label
        class='form-check-label'
        :for='id'>
        <slot/>
      </label>
    </div>
  `
})
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/prakqw8d/)

Comment: So the `v-model` will detect automatically if the swithc is toggled as I can see from the example, right?

Comment: Yes. Please read https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html, there is a Checkbox section.

Comment: Know about, but never used the toggle switch or checkbox in a form with vue. Thanks for the help